# Getting org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4 exception?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mapping, innodb

I am getting following exception at **query.list()** line:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
```

following is my configuration file:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_resource">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysql</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">mydatabase</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
```

When I am trying to run application into Eclipse IDE then this exception is not coming but when I create jar of application and run then only I am getting it.
thanks in advance...

Comment: make sure you have used proper dialect for the database that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

Just change the Query, I am fetching whole record instead of select specific.
e.g. **from table** and then get respective field (here script) value from table Object instead of using **select script from table**, It is working fine now.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes database returns results of custom SQL queries in strange types that cannot be mapped to Hibernate types (especially when you use expressions under `select`).

You need to find an offending query and add an explicit cast to it.

For example

```
Object o = session.createSQLQuery("select 2*2").uniqueResult();
```

may cause such a problem. You may fix it as follows:

```
Object o = session.createSQLQuery("select cast(2*2 as int)").uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Now I am getting org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query exception....
I have MEDIUMBLOB in my table so what should I have to give?