# Can' t Get column names of the Table using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i am using Hibernate to get Column names of the table.I Created one Method and I am passing my **Table Name** to that Method While executing  I am Getting This Exception :
**No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1** Could any one Help me out.Thanks

Below Mycode:

Dao class:

```
public class Dao {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Dao o=new Dao();
             ArrayList list=o.getTableDesc("examtype");
        System.out.println ("listlistlist"+list);
        }
    public  ArrayList<String>  getTableDesc(String tableName) {
            System.out.println("getFieldNames:start" + tableName);
            Object[] a;
            List<Object[]> fieldNames = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
            ArrayList<String> tabFieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            try {
                String queryStr = "DESCRIBE "  + tableName;                 
                fieldNames = (List<Object[]>) ses.createSQLQuery(queryStr).list();
                System.out.println("fieldNamesfieldNames"+fieldNames);
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.size(); i++) {
                    a = fieldNames.get(i);
                    tabFieldNames.add(a[0].toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("exception " + e);
            } finally {
                ses.close();
            }
            System.out.println("getFieldNames:end" + tabFieldNames.toString());
            return tabFieldNames;
        }  
    }
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306treamisdemo</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">30</property>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</property>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>       
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I am not a MySQL guy but this may help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985533/getting-org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-4-exc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the property name of dialect as follows:

name="dialect"
change it to
**name="hibernate.dialect"**

and should also add the mapping resource="path where the respective(entity class related as if Person entity-->Person.hbm.xml) hbm.xml file presents"

and run it.