# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 3

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I want to return the rows on like criteria i have 5 records at this criteria in the database but this code does not return , an exception is throws **org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 3**

```
 Query selectTxnList = session.createSQLQuery("select * from TxnList where txnRecNo in (select txnRecNo from TxnAdditionalInsured where clientName like :clientName)");

 selectTxnList.setParameter("clientName", "%" + istHelper.getAdditionalInsured() + "%");

 List list = selectTxnList.list();
```

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985533/getting-org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-4-exc

Comment: try setting this https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setEntity  look for setentity() on the query object.