# ORACLE SQL Difference between two dates hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, date

I need to calculate the difference between two dates into SQL dialect into my hibernate repository, i tried many solutions but for now it's not working, i keep getting this error:

> ***org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -104***

**NOTE: The query is working directly into DBeaver in SQL, but not into Spring.**

I'm working with Springboot, hibernate, oracle.

**I have to expose the calculated new time (as "Duration") trough my springboot REST controller into json like this format:
HH:mm:ss 
The idea is that i have a datatable on the front-end side, showing some info into a table, and i would like to show the calculated time.**

Here is my repository:

```
public interface BatchInfosJoinRepository extends JpaRepository<BatchInfosJoin, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT ji.JOB_NAME, bse.STEP_NAME, bse.STATUS,bse.START_TIME, bse.END_TIME, bse.END_TIME - bse.START_TIME AS DATE_DIFF " +
            " FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION bje INNER JOIN BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION bse ON bje.JOB_EXECUTION_ID = bse.JOB_EXECUTION_ID " +
            " INNER JOIN BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE ji ON ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = bje.JOB_INSTANCE_ID", nativeQuery = true)
    Set<Object[]> fetchStepJoin();
}
```

My model entity "BatchInfoJoin":

```
@Entity
public class BatchInfosJoin {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "step_execution_id")
    private Long stepExecutionId;

    @Column(name = "job_name")
    private String jobName;
    @Column(name = "step_name")
    private String stepName;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private Date startTime;
    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private Date endTime;
    @Column(name = "date_diff")
    private Date dateDiff;
}
```

Or maybe should i calculate it using an special "Util" class in Java?

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985533/getting-org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-4-exc

Comment: @XtremeBaumer : Thanks for the links, i have already seen them boths (i can' understand the first one), but could someone could provide a more specific answer to my problem?  For the second, how can i use the whole record (as mentionned into the stackoverflow link)  if want to make a precise select and return specific columns to my controller?

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27166944/10496246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
bse.END_TIME - bse.START_TIME AS DATE_DIFF
```

with

```
(bse.END_TIME - bse.START_TIME)*60*60*24 AS DATE_DIFF
```